# Изображение бэкграунда под мобильные устройства

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка, html, css

Добрый день.

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы бэкграунд автоматом растягивался либо под альбомное разрешение экрана, либо под портретное.

Сейчас при перевороте экрана в мобильных устройствах картинка, либо не дотягивает по высоте (landscape), либо искажается в (portrait)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать для этого блока

```
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
```

http://habrahabr.ru/post/157817/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
У меня получилось проще :)

img {width:100%;height:100%;}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
img {height:100%;display:block;top:0px;left:0px;width:200%;margin-left:-20%;}
}